# Is there an elegant way to handle run-time dependent object composition without using dynamic_cast?

Tags: design-patterns, c++, composition

**Context**

I'm attempting to design a modelling framework that is modular and easy to extend and test. (I'm trying to follow open/closed, dependency injection, and composition over inheritence principles).

I have a hierachy of model objects, which contain methods, some common to all and others specific to certain models. I also have a hierachy of estimation methods which work on various subsets of the models.

Each estimator class requires a model object, which is passed using the constructor.

While constructing the objects at compile is no problem, I'm struggling to come up with a way to do so in run-time without resorting to dynamic_casting of parent model interface in the estimator.
While it works, it's potentially unsafe if an invalid combination of model and estimator are put together. I've also read that dynamic_casting is usually a sign of poor code design.

**Question**

Are there any standard design patterns or techniques to avoid using *dynamic_cast* when object composition details are only known at run-time?

Or does this suggest the object hierachy needs to be completely reworked to avoid this kind of conditional dependency between objects?

**Code Example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

class i_model {
public:
    virtual double getparameter_a() = 0;
 };

class i_model_A : public i_model {
public:
    virtual double getparameter_b() = 0;
};

class model_A : public i_model_A {
public:
    double getparameter_a() { return 4.0; };
    double getparameter_b() { return 4.0; };
};

class i_model_B : public i_model {
public:
    virtual double getparameter_c() = 0;
};

class model_B : public i_model_B {
public:
    double getparameter_a() { return 5.0; };
    double getparameter_c() { return 2.0; };
};

class i_estimator {
public:
    virtual double getestimate() = 0;
};

class estimator_1 : public i_estimator {
public:
    estimator_1(i_model* in) : model(dynamic_cast<i_model_A*>(in)) {};
    double getestimate() { return model->getparameter_a() + model->getparameter_b(); };
private:
    i_model_A* model;
};

class estimator_2 : public i_estimator {
public:
    estimator_2(i_model* in) : model(dynamic_cast<i_model_B*>(in)) {};
    double getestimate() { return model->getparameter_a() + model->getparameter_c(); };
private:
    i_model_B* model;
};

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    i_model* model = nullptr;
    i_estimator* estimator = nullptr;

    std::cout << "Select model: ";
    std::cin >> a;

    std::cout << "\nSelect estimator: ";
    std::cin >> b;
    
    switch(a) {
    case 1: model = new model_A(); break;
    case 2: model = new model_B(); break;
    }

    switch (b) {
    case 1: estimator = new estimator_1(model); break;
    case 2: estimator = new estimator_2(model); break;
    }
    std::cout << "\nEstimator value = " << estimator->getestimate();
}
```

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68402131/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-handle-run-time-dependent-object-composition-without "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."